# Objective-C: "Hello world" COMPILED! without Foundation header. Why?

Tags: objective-c, c, compilation

Consider the following code:

```
//#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Hello World!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot understand why it could be built and run? w/out Foundation header!

**For me it is still strange that C compiler COMPILES this code w/out header i.e. w/out DECLARATIONS. It's strange that compiler matches my function somehow to already compiled code (Foundation) and succeeds. Are there some links to C standard that will explain me how compiler resolves token that recognized as a function and was never previously declared?**

Please, explain!!

UPDATE: These if not due to pre-compiled headers

Thank you! But NO. I tested it the following way - just typed Hello World code in vi editor and saved it as main.m file. Than compiled it with clang from Terminal. And e-thing went Okay with 1 warning only:

```
main.m:8:9: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'NSLog' with type 'void (id, ...)' NSLog(@"Hello World!");
^ main.m:8:9: note: please include the header <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'NSLog'
1 warning generated.
```

UPDATE: Just attaching all the images step-by-step:
[image: The only file in directory main.m]
[image: Contents of main.m - VIM]
[image: Compiling ... Compiled!]
[image: Test run of the application built]

Comment: Can you show your compile line?  Without a `-framework Foundation`, you shouldn't have successfully linked.

Comment: Doesn't work for me—using `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`, I get a bunch of undefined symbol errors during linking for `_NSLog`, `___CFConstantStringClassReference`, `_objc_autoreleasePoolPop` and `_objc_autoreleasePoolPush` as expected.  Can you post the command line you're using to compile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no reason it shouldn't compile.  As you're seeing, without that header present, the compiler is assuming `NSLog` is a function with signature `void NSLog(id, ...)`.  In this case, you're even luckier, because that signature happens to be compatible with the real function declaration - meaning your program will actually even *work* correctly as well:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

Note that without *linking* against Foundation, the build won't succeed:

```
$ make example
cc     example.m   -o example
example.m:3:9: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'NSLog' with type
      'void (id, ...)'
        NSLog(@"Hello World!");
        ^
example.m:3:9: note: please include the header <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h> or
      explicitly provide a declaration for 'NSLog'
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
      _main in example-943cd4.o
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in example-943cd4.o
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
      _main in example-943cd4.o
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
      _main in example-943cd4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [example] Error 1
```

You need to add `-framework Foundation`:

```
$ CFLAGS="-framework Foundation" make example
cc -framework Foundation    example.m   -o example
example.m:3:9: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'NSLog' with type
      'void (id, ...)'
        NSLog(@"Hello World!");
        ^
example.m:3:9: note: please include the header <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h> or
      explicitly provide a declaration for 'NSLog'
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: I find your use of "shouldn't" extremely confusing.  If the "it" refers to compiling, then yes, you are correct, there's no reason compiling shouldn't work.  But if the "it" is referring to the entire building+running, then it *shouldn't* work and it *doesn't*.  Until the OP posts the original command line being used, we can only speculate as to what he's doing.

Comment: I'll edit to be clearer.  OP's title says "compiles" so that's what I was going from.

Comment: Thank you Carl. You were initially right with your answer. For me it is still strange that C compiler COMPILES this code w/out header i.e. w/out DECLARATIONS. It's strange that compiler matches my function somehow to already compiled code (Foundation) and succeeds. Are there some links to C standard that will explain me how compiler resolves token that recognized as a function and was never previously declared?

Comment: And why compiler recognizes unknown function as 'void (id, ...)'? Is it declared somewhere in docs?

Comment: @DaddyM: It's a holdover from the C89 language standard, which treats any function call to an undeclared function as if that function had a declaration of `extern int identifier()` (i.e. taking an arbitrary number and type of parameters and returning `int`).  C99 removed implicit function declarations, and Objective-C is based on C99, but despite that, a number of compilers still allow it by default for compatibility with legacy code.

Comment: @DaddyM - Adam has it right.  Sometimes (often?) compilers allow not-strictly-conforming code through as a help to the programmer.  If you don't like it, there's always `-Wextra`, `-Werror`, and `-pedantic`.

Comment: The command CFLAGS="-framework Foundation" make example helped me a lot.

Comment: @CarlNorum  Thank! -framework 'FRAMEWORK_NAME' work!

Answer (score 2):

The foundation framework is probably imported in your precompiled header (.pch)

Comment: Thank you! But NO. I tested it the following way - just typed Hello World code in vi editor and saved it as main.m file. Than compiled it with clang from Terminal. And e-thing went Okay with 1 warning only:main.m:8:9: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'NSLog' with type
      'void (id, ...)'
        NSLog(@"Hello World!");
        ^
main.m:8:9: note: please include the header <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h> or
      explicitly provide a declaration for 'NSLog'
1 warning generated.

Answer (score 1):

Header files normally serve the purpose of instructing a compiler what to expect out of a function prototype. That being said, if the header file is not included ( which means in the absence of a function prototype), modern compilers like gcc and clang in this case try to 'infer' the prototype of a function when they are used in the code.

In this case, when the NSLog() function is called, the compiler tries to infer it's prototype and that's precisely the warning being issued. Additionally, these header files have no significance during link time; All the linker needs to know is 1) do i have function ( main() ) to enter and run the executable and 2) do i have the corresponding library / object code for all the symbols being used ( ofcourse am simplifying a bit here). So as long as the foundation library is made available to the linker (-fobjc-arc ) linking should go through fine.

As folks have already mentioned, not including header files is a bad practice. Because it helps compilers to catch issues up front and ensure the functions are called with appropriate data.

Comment: I like this answer. It is definitely describes how compilers work. Could you please provide me with references on compiler docs concerning function inferring process? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere that I can find, but clearly the `-fobjc-arc` command line flag is causing the linker to automatically link in Foundation.framework.

Without `-fobjc-arc`:

```
$ clang main.m
main.m:3:5: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'NSLog' with type
      'void (id, ...)'
    NSLog(@"Hello World!");
    ^
main.m:3:5: note: please include the header <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h> or
      explicitly provide a declaration for 'NSLog'
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
      _main in main-db9728.o
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in main-db9728.o
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
      _main in main-db9728.o
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
      _main in main-db9728.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

With `-fobjc-arc`:

```
$ clang main.m -fobjc-arc
main.m:3:5: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'NSLog' with type
      'void (id, ...)'
    NSLog(@"Hello World!");
    ^
main.m:3:5: note: please include the header <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h> or
      explicitly provide a declaration for 'NSLog'
1 warning generated.
```

[Carol Norum explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24210920/9530) why it compiles fine without including the proper header file.  Nevertheless, this is bad practice, and you should always include the proper header files you need and explicitly link against the frameworks you need.  It may work *this* time, but it may hide some insidious bugs and fail in spectacular ways with other code.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that this is bad practice. The fact that compiler resolved functions w/out proper header made me mad. That's why I requested the Community for clarifications.